# convex hull algorithm modified problemm

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures

I was recently asked this question in an interview, but I don't know the optimal approach. Can someone point me into right direction.

The Expected time complexity was O(nlogn) and space complexity required was O(1).

Comment: I doubt that space can be O(1) as the set of undefeatable pairs seems to be O(n). How would you encode the output of this?

Comment: @Vroomfondel It depends how you define the space complexity of an algorithm. Often you will not consider [the input and output size](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/83574/does-space-complexity-analysis-usually-include-output-space).

Comment: @Vroomfondel I mean other than the resulting set, auxiliary space should not be used.

Comment: Also show what you think or tried.

Comment: @J.Doe. why did you modify your question? It is impossible to understand what you want now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to compute the [pareto-frontier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_efficiency) or the [skyline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skyline_operator). Check [**Maxima of a point set**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxima_of_a_point_set) for an algorithm.

Since the space complexity should be O(1) it is mandatory to use an in-place sorting algorithm (with O(n log n) runtime complexity)

Comment: How does it help to achieve O(1) space-complexity?

Comment: For the algorithm described you only need to store the pair with the highest y-value seen so far. I don't see why this is not O(1) space. Maybe you can elaborate a bit more.

Comment: How will you sort the data with O(1) space-complexity?

Comment: I see, It's important to note the when looking at space complexity you usually [do not consider intput and output size](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/83574/does-space-complexity-analysis-usually-include-output-space). When you use in-place sorting you will not use more space than is already needed by the data.

Comment: The only in-place sorting algorithm with O(nlogn) time complexity is `Heap-sort`. So It is mandatory to use `Heap-Sort` to sort the data here to satisfy the requirements. You can add it to your answer!

Comment: @SaiBot Thanks a lot, but I think interviewer was looking for a more straightforward answer.

Comment: In worst case, `Heap-sort` can also make `log n` recursive calls. So in that case, Space-Complexity won't be `O(1)`.

Comment: @J.Doe. have you looked at the algorithm for two dimensions? I don't think it gets more easy than that.

Comment: @SaiBot Oh sorry, my bad. That was awesome. Thanks again.

Comment: @SanketMakani thank you for your comments. I included them in the answer. Are you talking about the heapify step? I think you could get rid of the recursion here. What do you think?

Comment: Any reference for in-place heap sort should be nice.

Comment: @J.Doe. beware however that the Wikipedia article describes a less-or-equal operation while your requirement is strictly less-than.

Comment: @SaiBot Well you can do it by converting it to iterative one but still Iterative approach requires extra memory as you are making only the "recursive call" iterative.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sort all pairs ascending by the x component. // O(n log n)
i=n, x = xn, ymax = yn, y = -infinity  // O(1)
for i = n-1 downto 0:   // O(n)
   if xi < x then x = xi, y = ymax
   if yi < y then mark pair as "defeated"
   else if yi > ymax then ymax = yi
```